# Why this CSS Transitions does not run smooth in OPERA and why it is slow in the ending (all browsers)?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WbbdQ/17/ runnning in OPERA and does not run smooth like CHROME/SAFARI.

Another questions, why in the ending of transitions (in all browsers) it decrease the speed? Notice, he takes no more than the appointed time (10 seconds), he just starts slow, gets faster and then slows down again at the end.

I'm running in a 1920px monitor, when you'll test if you can increase the results tab horizontally as much as possible.

Is normal this behavior in OPERA? And the decrease speed in end/start is normal too?

**About my Opera:**

Version: 11.62;
Build: 1347;
Platform: Win32;
System: Windows 7;

Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; en) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.62

Comment: Yes, easing is normal when you don't explicitly specify an easing value of `linear`.

Comment: @minitech And the lack of smoothness in OPERA, you have an explanation? Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I don't have Opera to try it out.

Comment: Opera is not so fast with transition other than transforms. Try the same with translation, it may help.

Comment: @mdi Translation? What you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> And the decrease speed in end/start is normal too?

Yes, this is normal as you can read in [the CSS Transitions specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transitions-20120403/#transition-timing-function-property). The `transition-timing-function` is default to `ease` (which means, slow begin and slow end). If you set this to `linear` (which means, normal from begin to end) it don't slow down in the begin/end.

---

I don't know the answer on the second question. The only thing I think is the problem is the fact of the very long duration(`10s`). It's too slow for the transition to work perfectly and it maybe could neck Opera and you get a slow transition.